# Laravel Sanctum with session issue when trying to logout and login

Tags: laravel, single-page-application, laravel-sanctum

I am using the latest version of Laravel Sanctum to create a validation method for my SPA, but I ran into an issue(notice that I dont work that long with laravel). When I login it works, but when I logout and try to login it stops working. After some testing I noticed that this was because of a cookie that was added by laravel.

// loginController

```
public function login(Request $request)
{

if ($this->validator($request->all())->fails()) {
    //validation stuff
} else {

    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ];

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->firstOrFail();

    if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {          

        $token = $user->createToken('auth')->plainTextToken;

        $response_code = 200;

        $response = [
            'user' => $user,
            'success' => true,
            'errors' => false,
            'message' => 'Login successfully',
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        ];

    } else {

        $response_code = 422;
        $response = [
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => [],
            'message' => 'Invalid login'
        ];
      
    }
}

public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $request->user()->tokens()->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you setup the stateful authentication in your laravel app with sanctum, to logout successfully do the following in the logout method:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    // invalidate the tokens
    Auth::user()->tokens()->delete();

    // Also invalidates the session/cookies
    $request->session()->invalidate();
}
```